# How to properly use cv2.pointPolyginTest() and cv2.findcontours()?

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to use cv2.pointPolygonTest to check if point is placed inside or outside contours, but I cannot figure out why it does not work.

This is the way I get contours:

```
img_name = a295121c-f893-43f5-8d00-6bfddbc19658.jpg"
im = cv2.imread(img_name)
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)
```

And this is how I check if point is inside or outside detected object.

```
    x1 = cv2.pointPolygonTest(contours[0], (x, y), False)
```

On this tresholded image it works fine:

[image: test1]

x1 is properly calculated when `(x,y)` is inside object

`np.shape(contours)` is equal to `(1, 241, 1, 2)`

However on this image:

[image]

all points are calculated as outside

`np.shape(contours)` is equal to `(11,)`

I suppose I don't use contours in a proper way, but I cannot figure out which dimension of contours should I pass to `cv2.pointPolygonTest()`

Comment: It's usually easier to draw the white filled contours on a black initialized binary mask (`drawContours`), and then each point has either values 0 (outside contour) or 255 (inside contour)

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if your code to test the point is only this:

```
 x1 = cv2.pointPolygonTest(contours[0], (x, y), False)
```

In this code, the function just test the first contour. Maybe in the second image there are multiple contours for please try to use a loop.